# Displaying whole table after stripping characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This question has 2 parts.

### Part 1

I have a table "Groups":

```
group_ID     person
-----------------------
1            Person 10
2            Person 11
3            Jack
4            Person 12
```

Note that not all data in the "person" column have the same format.

In SQL Server, I have used the following query to strip the "Person " characters out of the person column:

```
SELECT
REPLACE([person],'Person ','')
AS [person]
FROM Groups
```

I did **not** use UPDATE in the query above as I do not want to alter the data in the table.

The query returned this result:

```
person
------
10
11
12
```

However, I would like this result instead:

```
group_ID     person
-------------------
1            10
2            11
3            Jack
4            12
```

What should be my query to achieve this result?

### Part 2

I have another table "Details":

```
detail_ID     group1     group2
-------------------------------
100           1          2
101           3          4
```

From the intended result in Part 1, where the numbers in the "person" column correspond to those in "group1" and "group2" of table "Details", how do I selectively convert the numbers in "person" to integers and join them with "Details"?

Note that all data under "person" in Part 1 are strings (nvarchar(100)).

Here is the intended query output:

```
detail_ID     group1     group2
-------------------------------
100           10         11
101           Jack       12
```

Note that I do not wish to permanently alter anything in both tables and the intended output above is just a result of a SELECT query.

Comment: (1)  Your question is too broad because it is two questions.  (2) For the first part, the query should be doing what you want.

Comment: `SELECT group_ID, REPLACE([person],'Person ','') FROM ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think first part will be a problem here. Your query is working fine with your expected result.

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE #Groups (group_ID INT, person VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO #Groups
SELECT 1,'Person 10'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Person 11'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Jack'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'Person 12';


CREATE TABLE #Details(detail_ID INT,group1 INT, group2 INT);
INSERT INTO #Details
SELECT 100, 1, 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 101, 3, 4 ;
```

**Part 1:**

For me your query is giving exactly what you are expecting

```
SELECT group_ID,REPLACE([person],'Person ','') AS person 
FROM #Groups


+----------+--------+
| group_ID | person |
+----------+--------+
|        1 | 10     |
|        2 | 11     |
|        3 | Jack   |
|        4 | 12     |
+----------+--------+
```

**Part 2:**

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT group_ID
,REPLACE([person],'Person ','') AS person 
FROM #Groups
)
SELECT D.detail_ID, G1.person, G2.person
FROM #Details D
INNER JOIN CTE G1 ON D.group1 = G1.group_ID  
INNER JOIN CTE G2 ON D.group1 = G2.group_ID
```

**Result:**

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
| detail_ID | person | person |
+-----------+--------+--------+
|       100 | 10     | 10     |
|       101 | Jack   | Jack   |
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following query, it should give you the desired output.

```
;WITH MT AS
(
  SELECT
  GroupId, REPLACE([person],'Person ','') Person
  AS [person]
  FROM Groups
)
SELECT Detail_Id , MT1.Person AS group1 , MT2.Person AS AS group2    
 FROM    
Details D 
INNER JOIN MT MT1 ON MT1.GroupId = D.group1
INNER JOIN MT MT2 ON MT2.GroupId= D.group2
```

Answer (score 1):

The first query works

```
declare     @T table (id int primary key, name varchar(10));
insert into @T values 
       (1, 'Person 10')
     , (2, 'Person 11')
     , (3, 'Jack')
     , (4, 'Person 12');
declare     @G table (id int primary key, grp1 int, grp2 int);
insert into @G values  
       (100, 1, 2)
     , (101, 3, 4);
with cte as 
( select t.id, t.name, ltrim(rtrim(replace(t.name, 'person', ''))) as sp 
    from @T t 
)
-- select * from cte order by cte.id;
select g.id, c1.sp as grp1, c2.sp as grp2
  from @G g 
  join cte c1
    on c1.id = g.grp1 
  join cte c2
    on c2.id = g.grp2 
 order 
    by g.id;

id          grp1        grp2
----------- ----------- -----------
100         10          11
101         Jack        12
```